# Is stitching the best form of "fixing" an open slice wound in active combat where fire and ice magic exists? (Situation below)

Tags: magic, medical

Say a character manages to slice the external body open and guts are threatening to spill, the character sliced then falls back to feign their death, but instead tries to keep their organs closed from spilling and stitch their opening shut.

Would this be, in theory, the best way to quickly get back into a fight? Let's assume in the circumstance death is unavoidable, and the only goal is to distract an enemy for as long as possible, and said enemy thinks they can just leave them to die.

I see questions all over about people using ice and fire to seal wounds in worlds of magic, but let's say they're using the magic to hold or even make a needle and thread. Of course I know stitches risks opening with too much stress, but CAN it work better than the fire and ice method for a field medication, with proper stitching?

(For context to give a better answer, this character will absolutely die if it buys the people he protects more time to escape.)

Answer (score 4):

An open cut through the abdomen is invalidating not only because it exposes the guts to the open, but also because it is extremely painful. To give you a reference, when samurai committed ritual suicide via seppuku, which is they cut open their stomach, they had an assistant whose task was to behead them and avoid them the painful death that would have followed. That was considered an honorable death, while not having the assistant to shorten the sufferance was a dishonorable way to die.

Even if you character can stitch the wound (or seal it with magic, for what it matters) any movement involving using the core would be excruciatingly painful and this would severely hamper their combat capability to the point of almost zeroing it.

Comment: That sorta answers it, but is missing the direct statement of whether or not it would be better than the fire/frost thing. I must've made the situation too lethal for the answer to matter, that is my bad.

Comment: @DyingGuardian not necessarily, deadliness of wounds often can be based on the location the wound occurs in. EG. getting a nasty cut in the swamp vs in a hospital. If the initial lethality of the wound is drawn back a bit and the effects of having a wound in the location they are in increased you can have a stitchable wound that still likely spells death if they are too far from real medical aid. Poison, infection, parasites can all be things that are significantly more of a threat with an open wound.

Comment: Right, but the fundamental question of "Is stitching a better idea than burning a wound shut" remains. If the character needs to maintain high mobility, is burning a wound closed, despite being more likely to be infected, a better idea than stitching it if the character has to move a lot afterwards. How likely is a burned shut part of the body going to open vs a stitched shut part.